# How to extract "fields" from JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my spinet:

```
$scope.foodtypes = {
   'GRAINS': {
      'HOT': ['Rice','Beans','Sogum'],
      'ROOT': ['Yam','Potato','Cassava']
   }
}
```

I like to store the exact word "GRAINS" or "ROOT" in a variable for decision making:

something like:

if foodtypes is "GRAINS"
    then ......

if foottypes is "ROOT"
  then ......

Please how do I capture "GRAIN" or "ROOT" for use?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `foodtypes` is a JSON string that represents an object that has all food types as first-level key, you could do something like this:

`Object.keys(JSON.parse($scope.foodtypes));`

This will return an array of strings ["GRAINS", "ROOT"].

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" usually means that your data is already an object. So no need to do JSON.parse.

Comment: Thank you Kate, I am very grateful.